# Remove item from list based on listview selected item

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, selecteditem

I know this might sound a little basic but I'm stuck and I'm not sure how to proceed.

This is the Main Class:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
        {
            private ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(); 

            private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                 MyList.Add(new MyClass("Hello", "World"));
                 MyListview.Items.Add(new MyClass("Hello", "World"));
            }

            private void Delete_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                MyList.Remove((MyClass)MyListview.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
```

I have a list name `MyList` and a listview name `MyListview`. What I want is, when I press a button, to remove the MyListview's selected item from MyList items. So something like this:

```
MyList.Remove((MyClass)MyListview.SelectedItem);
```

But for some reason this is not working for me. Nothing gets deleted this way.

The XAML of my Main Page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App17.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App17"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button x:Name="Delete" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="140,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Click="Delete_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="442,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ListView x:Name="MyListview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="497" Margin="143,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="510"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And my class `MyClass` is:

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public MyClass(string title,string name) 
    { 
        Title = title; 
        Name = name; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: How are your lists set up? i.e Are both lists binding to the same collection? Perhaps a more detailed look at your code would be the way forward here. Could you post some XAML?

Comment: Bindings are one way. I have 2 textblocks in a usercontrol which I use for the datatemplate of the listview. 1 textblock is binded to `Title` and the other to `Name` property

Comment: Do you mean something like `MyList.Remove((MyClass)MyListview.SelectedItem);`? Also you can edit your question and post code from the comment in the question

Comment: @user2975038 Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take some effort to actually ask a proper question. This is not a message board for interactive problem solving or debugging though discussions in comments. Include all relevant information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had some trouble making sure I am really testing the code you actually want help with. But I think I have seen enough to understand what the problem you are having is.

Specifically: you don't have any connection between the `ListView` where the items are displayed, and the private `MyList` collection where you are storing the items.

In XAML-based apps, the whole point is to connect your data to the visual representation via bindings. One primary reason `ObservableCollection<T>` exists is to facilitate this, to allow collection-based visuals to react to changes in the collection.

In your example, you should make the following changes…

Change `MainPage` so that its constructor and `Button_Click()` method look like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = MyList;
}

private ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();

private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyList.Add(new MyClass("Hello", "World"));
}
```

The above removes the extraneous call to `MyListview.Items.Add()` (not needed when the data is bound correctly) and assigns your `MyList` collection as the `DataContext` for the page, making it available for binding purposes.

Then change the XAML so that the `ListView` declaration looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListview"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="497" Width="510"
          Margin="143,261,0,0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

The key thing there is the `ItemsSource` attribute. Using an empty `Binding`, the control will use the current data context, which here will be inherited from the page object, which you've set in your code to be `MyList`.

In this way, you need only to operate on `MyList` itself, and the visual representation will update automatically.

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you very much!! You are the Best. Worked like a charm :D
I'm still kinda new to the bindings but this surely opened my eyes a little bit ;) thank you!!

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing? or should I make a new question for this? I have  2 listviews and depending on a string property `Status`, that can be either "Yes" or "No", items go to the apropriate listview. Should I make 2 more sublists? and if yes , how can I bind them to my main one MyList?

Comment: If you want details, you need a new question, 'cause I can't fit it all in a comment. :) But briefly: instead of directly to the collection, you can bind through an `ICollectionView` object, which you can obtain from [`CollectionViewSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.100).aspx). You can use the filtering feature of `ICollectionView` to show only the ones that are "Yes" or "No", as appropriate for the given `ListView` (i.e. one `ICollectionView` per `ListView`). Then the single list is presented in two different ways.